# Playframework [1.2.5]: How to use SSL

Tags: playframework

I have an ssl config file and I want to use https to secure my application.

I found a solution like below, but I did not understand how to use it.

```
https.port=9443
trustmanager.algorithm=JKS
keystore.file=conf/certificate.jks
keystore.password=password
certificate.password=password
```

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfiguringHttps

Answer (score 1):

Three things here:

**Use Later Versions**: Why you still stuck with Play 1?!. It is a very old version. It lacks so many features. In fact, if you are afraid of security issues, you should always use the latest version.

**Use Nginx instead**: You could use Nginx as a front http server, which redirects the traffic into your play application, running at `localhost:9000`. In terms of SSL it is very simple to setup https. In fact you could use 'certbot' to do it for you.

**Don't forget port 443**: Having said the above points, the solution you posted, looks like environment variabls that should be added to your `application.conf`; however its port does not makes sense. The port should be `443`.